# passing in an instance method into a python multiprocessing Process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

If I pass in a reference to an instance method instead of a module level method into `multiprocessing.Process`, when I call it's start method is an exact copy of the parent process instance passed in or is the constructor called again? What happens with 'deep' instance member objects? Exact copy or default values?

Answer (score 3):

Instances are not passed between processes, because instances are per Python VM process.

Values passed between processes are `pickle`d. Unpickling normally restores instances by measures other than calling `__init__`; As far as I can tell it directly sets attribute values to resurrect an instance, and resolves references to/from other instances.

Provided that you run identical code in either process (and with `multiprocessing`, you do), it restores a reference to a correct instance method inside a restored chain of instances.

This means that if an `__init__` in the chain of objects does something side-effectful, it will *not* have been done on the receiving side, that is, in a subprocess. Do such initialization explicitly.

All in all, it's easiest to share (effectively) immutable objects between parallel processes, and reconcile results after `join()`ing all of them.

Comment: What do you mean by resolving references to other instances? Say one of the instance attributes was a db connection object. How would such a stateful attribute be recreated?

Comment: Imagine serializing `and de-serializing ('a', 'b')`. Once `'a'` and `'b'` have been restored, a `tuple` instance is re-created, and is made to point to the newly created stings as first and second elements. Same applies to nearly all instance attributes: you rarely serialize a single object without moving parts, and all moving parts are references to other objects. It will obviously _not_ work with serializing a db connection object. Serializing it is not a good idea, but still there is [an escape hatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-external-objects).